# Woocommerce and PayPal php error

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

When trying to checkout i get this error:

```
[30-Oct-2017 21:23:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Subscription_Legacy::get_name() in /home/usmiledk/public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php:37
```

The user just gets redirected back to home base, after entering order details in PayPal. On the backend it says pending payment, but the setting is set to take instant payments - nor can i see anything on the paypal express backend. What's going on her?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that the theme is using an undefined method. Try updating the theme and WC Subscriptions and WooCommerce. You can also try looking at the mini-cart.php file line 37 and amending the code to get the product title properly.